# Does cross product have an identity?

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

Does cross product have an identity?  I.e. Does there exist some  $\vec{id}\in \mathbb{R}^3$ such that 
$$\vec{id} \times \vec{v} = \vec{v}\times \vec{id} = \vec{v}
$$ 
for all $\vec{v}\in \mathbb{R}^3$?

Comment: You question is unclear. Are all these "somevector" in the identity the same? What is your question?

Comment: my question is that given $\vec{u}\in\mathbb{R}^3$, does there $\exists \vec{v}\in\mathbb{R}^3$ such that $\vec{v}\times\vec{u}$ = $\vec{u}\times\vec{v}$ =$\vec{u}$.

Comment: @Jack Hopefully my edit correctly reflects the question.  I agree that the original wording was unclear whether he hoped $v$ or $i$ was the identity.  As for your question Raton, you should know that if $u\times v = w$ that $\langle u,w\rangle = \langle v,w\rangle = 0$.  I.e. the result of the cross product of two vectors is a third vector which is perpendicular to both of the original two.  If such an identity existed, then every vector would be perpendicular to itself.  Contradiction.

Comment: So you're basically saying that only if $\vec{v}=\vec{0}$ there exists an $\vec{id}$ that produces $\vec{v}$ when crossed with $\vec{id}$? and any vector id can play such a role?

Comment: @JMoravitz: +1 for your editing.

Comment: Will you let me embed your problem into $\Bbb{R}^4$.  I.e., reformulate as: "Is there a vector $\vec{v} \in \Bbb{R}^4$ such that for all vectors $\vec{u}=(x,y,z,0)$ (a subspace of $\Bbb{R}^4$ that is vector space isomorphic to $\Bbb{R}^3$), we have $\vec{u} = \vec{v} \times \vec{u} = \vec{u} \times \vec{v}$?".

Comment: @EricTowers , if you want to ask it as a new question feel free, but I don't see editing this one to read $\mathbb{R}^4$ to be consistent with this specific problem as it reads.

Comment: Why should cross products be limited to $\Bbb{R}^3$?  Your first sentence asks about cross products without specifying a space.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The answer must be no because $\vec{id}\times \vec{v}$ is perpendicular to both $\vec{id}$ and $\vec{v}$ and the only vector that is perpendicular to itself is the $0$ vector. Thus $\vec{id}\times \vec{v}=\vec{v}$ iff $\vec{v}=\vec{0}$ no matter what $\vec{id}$ is, so this cannot be true in general.

Answer (score 19):

Note that for any potential identity vector $\vec u$, we have
$$
\vec u \times \vec v + \vec v \times \vec u = \vec 0
$$
for any vector $\vec v$.

Comment: I like this rational over the others because it seems more innate to me, without using extra structure on the space.

Answer (score 7):

Perhaps even easier.  Suppose such a vector $\vec{id}$ exists.  First note that $\vec{id} = 0$ does not work, so $\vec{id} \ne 0$.

Applying the desired property with $\vec{v} = \vec{id}$ we get
$$\vec{id} \times \vec{id} = \vec{id}$$
By antisymmetry, any vector cross itself is 0.  So this is a contradiction.